# Questions about COBs and power supplies from a beginner

Tags: voltage, led, watts, cob

I'm planning to use Citizen 1212 COBs, but I don't know how they can be used on 70 watt for each one of them, knowing that each unit will have 5 COBs. So my question is: what is the right power supply for me to run these on parallel? And if they were installed on it directly without any circuit controlling the voltage or amperage, how many volts/amperes will they be using?

Comment: We don't know what  COBs is

Comment: COB stands for Chip on Board and is used with LED lighting where a number of LED chips are combined into one module to form a more uniform lighting panel than can be achieved with separate LEDs.

Comment: There are many different types of Citizen 1212 COBs so you need to be more specific with the exact model you intend to use and how you are going to connect them.

Answer (score 1):

These COBs (and most of them) are current-driven, which means you need a current driver, not a voltage source.

It also means that you cannot connect them in parallel. You could if by adding some small resistor in series to each COB to compensate for the voltage differential, but it is not very safe and they may end up dying after some time.

In your situation, the best two options are to connect them in series and have a current source that has a voltage high enough to drive them or use an independent driver for each.

Note that if you are going to drive them at 70W, you need to have some good cooling, otherwise you will kill them.